# How to get a specific value on a json node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

Guys how can I get a value in a json?  Look...

This is my json file:

```
[{"usuario": "test", "email": "teste@hotmail.com", "senha": "test"},  
{"usuario": "test 2", "email": "teste2@gmail.com", "senha": "test2"}]
```

This is my js node code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const logins = fs.readFileSync("./logins.json", "utf8")                                         
console.log(logins)
```

I tried to replace this line:

```
console.log(logins)
```

For this:
console.log(logins.usuario)

But it doesn't work, why doesn't it work?  How can I get all users, or a specific user, like my attempt above.

I also tried it this way:

```
console.log(logins["test 2"])
```

**Edite:**

Maybe I have more than 2 pieces of information in this json, I need to access the username or some other value if necessary

Comment: the data is an Array of Objects ... do you know how to access an element of an Array? hint: an array's can't use strings as element indexes, they must use integers

Comment: When my json was without the `[]` I also couldn't access

Comment: What does console.log(logins) show? Check that and let us know

Comment: when your json was without `[]` you could only have a single object, which you WOULD access using `console.log(logins.usuario)` to output `"test"` ... and `console.log(logins.email)`  to output `"teste@hotmail.com"` ... etc

Comment: @Tushar Shahi It's to show json

Comment: Apologies, I rephrased my statement.

Comment: Ah, so that was it, I was leaving without the `[]` and I put more than one object in json

Comment: @Tushar Shahi `[{"usuario": "test", "email": "teste@hotmail.com", "senha": "test"},
{"usuario": "test 2", "email": "teste2@gmail.com", "senha": "test2"}]`

Comment: It is an array. As @JaromandaX mentioned, you will have to do something like logins[0].usuario or logins[1].usuario

Comment: If it is still a string, then try using `JSON.parse(logins)`

Comment: I already edited question

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string to json, using `JSON.parse(logins)`

An example of how to parse a field after converting it into an object

```
const fs = require("fs");
const logins = fs.readFileSync("./logins.json", "utf8")
var obj = JSON.parse(logins)
var email = obj[0]['email']
var email2 = obj[1]['email']
var user = obj[0].senha
var user2 = obj[1].senha
console.log(email2,email,user,user2)
```

[image]

Comment: Error: `Undefined`

Comment: @Gjsks You can access object values by using dot (.) notation or [].  JSON notation is `{'key':'value'}`

Answer (score 1):

to read JSON you can use "require" and then content will be parsed correctly:

```
const logins = require("./logins.json")
const email = logins[0]['email'];
```